# How To Save Re-Ordered Tableview Cells To Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, reorderlist

So I have my `tableview` when I re-order my rows it updates the `tableview` and everything but it isn't saving to `core data`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let movedCampSites = itemName[sourceIndexPath.item]
    itemName.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    itemName.insert(movedCampSites, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
    context.delete(itemName[sourceIndexPath.row])
    context.insert(itemName[destinationIndexPath.row])

    do
    {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Could not move rows")
    }



}
```

Everything works up till `context.insert(itemName[destinationIndexPath.row])` for example if I comment that out and run it, it will move the rows and delete the row and save to `core data`, but the `context.insert` doesn't save the new row position. For some reason it is running my catch block as I am getting the error Could not move rows.

Here is some of the error that is in the console.

2018-07-22 09:27:01.884925-0700 Search Bar Core Data[67957:5383630] [error] error: (1555) UNIQUE constraint failed: ZTITLE.Z_PK
CoreData: error: (1555) UNIQUE constraint failed: ZTITLE.Z_PK
Could not move rows

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the perspective of Core Data there is no difference because it saves objects unordered.

Comment: Okay so how could I change this so that is works?

Comment: If you need a specific order use or add a Core Data attribute which can be sorted in this order (for example an Int32 index)

Comment: I'd appreciate a green checkmark if this answer is correct =D

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on this issue:

Like 'vadian' said, when you create an object you add a property for the array that appends to the Core Data, like this,

```
var itemsArray: [NSManagedObject] = []

save(sortOrder: itemsArray.count, item: itemTextField.text!) //Calling the save method wherever you need to, catching for example a UITextField user input

private func save(sortOrder: Int, item: String) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CoreDataBaseName", in: context) else { return }
    let itemManagedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    itemManagedObject.setValue(sortOrder, forKeyPath: "sortOrder")
    itemManagedObject.setValue(item, forKeyPath: "item")

    do {
        try context.save()
        itemsArray.append(itemManagedObject)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save item to Core Data: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Then we come to the tableView's moveRowAt method,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let movedItem = itemsArray[sourceIndexPath.row]

    itemsArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    itemsArray.insert(movedItem, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    //This 'for-in loop' is at the heart of the solution
    for (i, item) in itemsArray.enumerated() {
        item.setValue(i, forKey: "sortOrder")
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save/persist Core Data items in moveRowAt: \(error)")
    }
}
```

... And at the end of everything we fetch the rearranged order with,

```
private func fetch() {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "CoreDataBaseName")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortOrder", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        itemsArray = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch Core Data entities: \(error)")
    }
}
```

There's a million different ways that you can improve this idea (which is always welcome), but this is a pedagogical example of a solution.

I hope it can help somebody out there!