# How to update the model after tableView was edited

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I am learning Swift by writing a single table app view which lists the content of a Core Data table (entity) upon start-up. Then the user can reorder the rows in the table view.

I need to be able to save the newly ordered rows such that they replace the previous database table, so when the user starts the app again, the new order is shown.

The editing (re-ordering) feature is activated by a long press and calls

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.projectTableView.moveRow(at: sourceIndexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)
}
```

A second long press then inactivates the editing feature:

```
    // Called when long press occurred
    @objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.projectTableView)
        if let indexPath = projectTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            if self.projectTableView.isEditing == true {
                self.projectTableView.isEditing = false
                db.updateAll()  //this is a stub
            } else {
                self.projectTableView.isEditing = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The call to db.updateAll() in 'handleLongPress' above is just a blank, and I don't know how to update the database. Is there a way to read the content of the tableView in the new sequence into an array, then replace the table in the db? Feels a little "brute force" but can't see any other solution.

Comment: Maybe updating your data source (by removing and re-inserting the item) when `moveRowAt` is called would be better?

Comment: @Sylvan can you add a code example?

Comment: Records in Core Data are stored unordered. If you want a specific order you have to add an `index` attribute and fetch the data sorted by `index`. In `moveRowAt` you have to adjust the indices. Just moving the rows will never affect the Core Data stack.

Comment: @vadian does CoreData have an 'id autoincrement' or similar integer that one can implement and get? Very surprised that such a trivial (in SQLite) function is not easily accessible in CoreData.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok you can achieve that in several ways :

1- Using `NSFetchedResultsController` , here you can automatically synchronizing changes made to your core data persistence store with a table view, 
    so quickly here are the steps :

- Conform to `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`
- Declare an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` with you core data model
- Make an `NSFetchRequest`, call `NSFetchedResultsController` initializer with the request, then assign it to your instance declared before
- call `performFetch` method on your instance
- set the viewController to be the delegate
- And now you can implement the delegates, here you want `didChange` , so something like that :

  ```
  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
              didChange anObject: Any,
              at indexPath: IndexPath?,
              for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
              newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
       switch type {
       /*
         ....
        */
       case .move:
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
               self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [deleteIndexPath], with: .fade)
             }

            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: .fade)
            }
       }
  ```

  }

2- Second option which personally i prefer it over the NSFetchedResultscontroller

You can add a property in your model (core data model). That can be an Int for example "orderNum".
So when you fetch request you can order the result using this prperty.

So if your table view cell re-arranged, after implementing moveItem method you can update this property for all your objects(loop over them) and they will be as they are displayed.

try to save your managed object context now,

Next time when you want to fetch request you can use a sort descriptor to sort on the "orderNum".

Comment: This is a good idea that I answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467055/how-to-save-re-ordered-tableview-cells-to-core-data/62200197#62200197

Answer (score 1):

Maybe updating your data source (by removing and re-inserting the item) when moveRowAt is called would be better?

So something like:

```
// assuming your data source is an array of names
var data = ["Jon", "Arya", "Tyrion", "Sansa", "Winterfell"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.projectTableView.moveRow(at: sourceIndexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)

    let item = self.data.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    if sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row {
        // "Sansa" was moved to be between "Jon" and "Arya"
        self.data.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row
    } else {
        // if the new destination comes after previous location i.e. "Sansa"
        // was moved to the end of the list
        self.data.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row - 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually @mojtaba's suggestion of having an `orderNum` value for your items would be the better solution